# Как правильно выполнить gestureRecognizer swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, swift3, ios8

Учусь работать с iOS вот нашел пример как выполнить распознавание жестов

Вот так это выглядит в примере

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

И точно так же я реализовал это в своей имплементацию

---

```
import UIKit

class FaceViewController: UIViewController {
var expression = FacialExpression(eyes: .Open, eyeBrown: .Normal,  mouth: .Smile) {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView! {
    didSet {
        faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(
                target: faceView, action:   #selector(FaceView.changeScale(_ :))
        ))
        updateUI()
    }
}
```

---

```
class FaceView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var scale: CGFloat = 0.9 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var mouthCurvature: Double = 1.0 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var eyesOpen: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var eyebrowTilt: Double = 0.5 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var color: UIColor = UIColor.blue {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 5.0 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

func changeScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .changed, .ended:
        scale *= recognizer.scale
        recognizer.scale = 1.0
    default: break
    }
}
```

---

Но у меня показывает ошибку `Type FaceView has no member changeScale`

и насколько я понимаю то это логично так как я пытаюсь обратиться к ней как к статическому методу `FaceView.changeScale`, но это метод объекта...

Но как тогда это работает в примере? Может разница в версиях свифта?

И потом, если я делаю эту функцию статической, то она естественно просит как параметр `recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer` , но я не могу передать его так как он не инициализирован...

В общем не понятно как это работает в примере и не работает у меня...

Что сделал не так ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По названию передаваемого параметра у Вас должно быть не

```
#selector(FaceView.changeScale(_:))
```

а

```
#selector(FaceView.changeScale(recognizer:))
```

В остальном все правильно. Это не вызов статического метода.

Comment: да действительно... Спасибо . Я так понимаю это уже в свифт 3 внесено, так как в примере нет этого параметра. Ок буду внимательнее в параметрам

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko , да, в Swift 3 небольшие изменения внесли в этом плане. К примеру, если `func changeScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)` то так `FaceView.changeScale(recognizer:)`. А если `func changeScale(_ recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)` то так `FaceView.changeScale(_:)`.